# How do i edit my table in jsp page without opening new page to edit and it should reflects in database?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

when i edit table and hitting update , after that if i press view button the contents of table set to null.. please help me out of this..

This is my `index.jsp` page used to retrieve data from database.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String database = "test";
String userid = "root";
String password = "root";
try {
Class.forName(driver);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<html>
<body>
<!-- <h1>Retrieve data from database in jsp</h1> -->
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>first name</td>
<td>last name</td>
<td>City name</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>update</td>
</tr>
<%
try{
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+database, userid, password);
statement=connection.createStatement();
String sql ="select * from users";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
<tr>
<td  contenteditable><%=resultSet.getString("id") %></td>
<td  contenteditable><%=resultSet.getString("first_name") %></td>
<td  contenteditable><%=resultSet.getString("last_name") %></td>
<td  contenteditable><%=resultSet.getString("city_name") %></td>
<td  contenteditable><%=resultSet.getString("email") %></td>
<td><a href="update-process.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("id")%>">update</a></td>
</tr>
<%
}
connection.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This my `update-process.jsp`, this is used to store data back to database.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%! String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";%>
<%!String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";%>
<%!String user = "root";%>
<%!String psw = "root";%>
<%
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String first_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
String last_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
String city_name=request.getParameter("city_name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
if(id != null)
{
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
int personID = Integer.parseInt(id);
try
{
Class.forName(driverName);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,psw);
String sql="Update users set id=?,first_name=?,last_name=?,city_name=?,email=? where id="+id;
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,id);
ps.setString(2, first_name);
ps.setString(3, last_name);
ps.setString(4, city_name);
ps.setString(5, email);
int i = ps.executeUpdate();
if(i > 0)
{
out.print("Updated");
}
else
{
out.print("There is a problem in updating Record.");
} 
}
catch(SQLException sql)
{
request.setAttribute("error", sql);
out.println(sql);
}
}
%>

<html>
<body>
<form action="index.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="view">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Don't write java code in jsp. write a separate servlet for that. What error/exception are you getting?

Comment: after editing my table if press update ,that change should be reflect in database. But after updating the values in database are set to null;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'll suggest you not to put any java code in jsp. Your code looks very messy and its hard for bug finding and further maintenance. I'm not sure about it but as per below lines of code:

```
String first_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
String last_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
String city_name=request.getParameter("city_name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
```

you will always get null because you are no where having these input fields. The input fields generate request params or you need to append those requestParams in your access url like you have done for id.

Edit: In your index.jsp change:

```
<td><a href="update-process.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("id")%>">update</a></td>
```

to

```
<td><a href='update-process.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("id")%>&first_name=<%=resultSet.getString("first_name")%>&last_name=<%=resultSet.getString("last_name")%>&city_name=<%=resultSet.getString("city_name")%>&email=<%=resultSet.getString("email")%>'>update</a></td>
```

But its a very bad approach to do this.
Better you write one servlet, have a html form in index.jsp with all the input fields.

Comment: no bro its not working...ya i will write servlet  for that. ty